# overloading __getitem__ to support different access arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to simplify code and I figured I can overload **getitem** to act like both a list and a dictionary. Is there a reason I should not do this?

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page_id = []
        self.page = []

    def __getitem__(self, ref):
        if type(ref) is int:
            return self.page[ref]
        elif type(ref) is str:
            page_index = self.page_id.index(ref)
            return self.page[page_index]
```

This way I can support something like this

```
book = Book()
page_1 = book[5]
page_8 = book['id_for_page_8']
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. But that's just me. Maybe someone else might come along and find something wrong with it. :P Very minor, but you can save a line of code and just do: `self.page[self.page_id.index(ref)]`

Comment: My biggest concern is that type checking is stigmatized in python and here I rely on it.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. The way I see it, is that you are supporting two ways of retrieving the page from your code. If you are uncomfortable with this approach, you can create two methods that are more explicit. Like `get_by_index` or `get_by_id`. Something along those lines.

Comment: Personally, I like being more explicit with my design. However, someone else can come along and really justify doing your initial approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be more pythonic by simply doing a try/except

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page_id = []
        self.page = []

    def __getitem__(self, ref):
        try:
            return self.page[ref]   # assume it's an int
        except TypeError:
            return self.page[self.page_id.index(ref)] # assume it's a string if not an int
```

As a general tip, using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is a better choice over [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) because isinstance understands inheritance.